# Why does ImmutableDictionary.GetValueOrDefault return null here?

Tags: f#

Here is some code using `ImmutableDictionary`:

```ml
open System.Collections.Immutable

let dict = ImmutableDictionary.Create()

let key = "abc"

dict = dict.Add(key, "xyz")

dict.GetValueOrDefault(key) 
|> printfn "%A"
```

The output is `<null>`.

Why is it not `"xyz"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` below is **not an assignment**:

```
dict = dict.Add(key, "XYZ")
```

but an **equality check**: this check results in `false`, and that value is discarded.

---

`dict` is an immutable dictionary, and `dict.Add(key, "XYZ")` returns a new dictionary that has the newly added entry. So, you can instead mark the value `dict` as `mutable` and use the assignment (`<-`) to assign it the new resulting dictionary:

```
open System.Collections.Immutable

let mutable dict = ImmutableDictionary.Create()

let key = "abc"

dict <- dict.Add(key, "xyz")

dict.GetValueOrDefault(key) 
|> printfn "%A"
```

The output now is `"xyz"`.

Comment: Whoops! that's what you get for reading C# examples :)